# pinch and pan is not working when use together on a image

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

how pinch and pan on same image.

Pinch works fine but If you pinch than pan... image doesnt move/pan

code [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/pan)

**below is a home page class. here i am displaying a image from back end and using my container class to pinch and pan**

```
<local:PinchPanContainer>
            <local:PinchPanContainer.Content>
                <AbsoluteLayout  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image x:Name="FullScreenImage"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </local:PinchPanContainer.Content>
            </local:PinchPanContainer>
```

**below is my container class - which has a pinch and pan method**

variables

```
        double currentScale = 1;
        double startScale = 1;
        double xOffset = 0;
        double yOffset = 0;
```

pinch method

```
        void OnPinchUpdated(object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started)
            {
                // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
                // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
                startScale = Content.Scale;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running)
            {
                // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
                currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
                currentScale = Math.Max(1, currentScale);

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the X pixel coordinate.
                double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
                double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
                double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
                double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

                // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
                // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
                double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
                double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
                double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
                double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

                // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
                double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
                double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

                // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
                Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp(-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
                Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp(-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

                // Apply scale factor.
                Content.Scale = currentScale;
            }
            if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed)
            {
                // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
            }
        }//end of pinch method
```

Pan method

```
        void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
                    Content.TranslationX =
                      Math.Max(Math.Min(0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs(Content.Width - Application.Current.MainPage.Width));
                    Content.TranslationY =
                      Math.Max(Math.Min(0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs(Content.Height - Application.Current.MainPage.Height));
                    break;

                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    // Store the translation applied during the pan
                    x = Content.TranslationX;
                    y = Content.TranslationY;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I test your code, can fire pinch and pan method, having no problem? What  problem do you have?

Comment: thanks for getting back. 1st issue is, for some reason my image shows up location top left and it doesnt `HorizontalOptions` fill the screen. 2nd issue is, Pan only works one time, for exammple if you pan to right. than it wont pan again after than

Comment: do you mind posting your code? maybe i missed something

Comment: I use your code, just remove AbsoluteLayout , don't modify other.

Comment: i am also stuck on this issue for months now. can some one pleaseee post a quick solution?  @CherryBu-MSFT